# Java Executing one thread and make others on waiting mode

Tags: java, synchronization, mutex, synchronized

So I have a block of code that contains a `method` which allows users to search for a record's value from the database,
If the record exist an exception will be generated
Else the record will be added to the table.

So what I want to do is to stop all threads in the search `method`, and let only one thread to add the record into the table, and the that Thread is done I will call the `.notify` method to wake the other threads.

> let's consider this is my code

```
    //first step
       public static Object locker= new locker();
  -1     synchronized(locker){                              
  -2     res = ps.executeQuery();
  -3      lock.wait()
        }
    
    //second step 
   -4  dbaccess.add(record) // let's consider this will add my record to the table
   -5  lock.notify();
```

with this code the thread will be stuck and never executed what i want to do is to make one works and others waiting until I call the notify() in the 5th step

Comment: Your database engine should be handling concurrency for you.

Comment: You need to learn about database isolation and transaction managers.  Your thread code is not the way to do it.

Comment: @BasilBourque i want to handle everything in the server side  because im using different database types and that's the idea to handle these constraints in the server side

Comment: @duffymo i know the unique constraints and all of these things , but i want to handle everything in the server side by code implementation

Comment: Good luck. I think your way is a very bad idea.